# Kivy: Padding TextFieldMD in MDList

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to change the size of my label and TextField, and I'm using MDList with it.

The label and TextField is touching the screen in y axis, both sides. How to padding them for they don't touch the screen? I tried to use size_hint, pos_hint and size, and nothing worked.

````
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.selection import *
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.lang import Builder
import os
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"

KV = '''
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: 'telaAdicionar'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                id: toolbar
                md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            TelaAdiciona:
                id: telaadiciona
                
<TelaAdiciona>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            spacing: '20dp'
            
            MDLabel:
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Text: '
                font_style: 'H5'
                size_hint: (None, .5)
                
            MDTextField:
                id: nomeReceita
                font_size: self.width / 30
                mode: 'rectangle'
                #pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                #size_hint: (None, .5)

'''

class TelaAdiciona(FloatLayout):
    pass    

class Aplicativo(MDApp):    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
            
Aplicativo().run()```
````

Comment: Would you please clarify this *'I'd like to change it for they don't...'* ? Did you mean `padding` ?

Comment: Yes. I've changed the ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MDList` is intended to be used with [BaseListItem](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/list/index.html#module-kivymd.uix.list.list). But as it is inherited from `GridLayout` you can always use the attr. `padding` something like this,

```
        MDList:
            spacing: '20dp'
            padding: '25dp'
```

Comment: Worked man. Thanks a lot. I was trying to set padding in TextField and not in MDList.